# PropTypes isRequired on React Router 4 params prop

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have props been passed from React router in its match > params object which I want to be set in my static propTypes as a required string value. 
When I set it as photo: PropTypes.string.isRequired I get an error.

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `photo` is marked as required in `BlogEntry`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

When I do a log of what is coming in via the router props I can see photo is a string id.

```
const {match:{params:{photo}}} = this.props;
console.log("photo = ", photo);
// result: 
photo =  5a03c474e1bbc026de896aa8
```

Is there any way of having a required type validation on photo ?

Here is my setup.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {fetchBlogEntry} from '../../actions/index';
import BlogPost from '../../components/client/blog-post';

class BlogEntry extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    console.log('constructor = ', this.props.match.params.photo);
  }

  static propTypes={
    entry: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    photo: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    const {match:{params:{photo}}} = this.props;
    console.log("photo = ", photo);
    this.props.fetchBlogEntry(photo);
  }

  render(){
    const {entry} = this.props;
    return(
      <div id='blog' className='container'>
        <BlogPost {...entry}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({blog:{entry}}){
  return{
    entry
  }
}

export default connect(({blog:{entry}}) => ({entry}), {fetchBlogEntry})(BlogEntry);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to type check photos and it comes from React Router you have to change your props to expect it to be in match.

For example if I want to type check `props.match.params.name` my proptypes
would be:

```
  match: PropTypes.shape({
    params: PropTypes.shape({
      name: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    })
  }),
```

Comment: Excellent thanks. Could you explain shape a little more than what the docs says which is not much. "An object taking on a particular shape". Apart from using shape on nested objects what does it mean or do exactly. Or is it just that ( allows for nested props validation )

Comment: Also one little correction if anyone else tries your code. name: Proptypes.string.isRequired should be name: PropTypes.string.isRequired. Capital T in PropTypes.

Comment: Shape just allows you to describe the fields in an object. So instead of just saying it's an object you can say its an object that looks like this. There are other prop-types for describing objects too, like `objectOf`, but they aren't as descriptive. Also I fixed my example.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation Dakota :)